# Tomcat (on RHEL/CentOS) and ProtectionDomain

Tags: java, tomcat, tomcat7

I'm in the process of migrating a WAR from an Ant build to a Maven build. In the Ant build, our code was packaged into a JAR which was placed in `WEB-INF/lib`. With Maven, we're going with the standard behavior of compiling class files into `WEB-INF/classes`.

We have a class that tries to determine if a (reflectively-referenced) class comes from our WAR. This is done by looking at classes' `ProtectionDomain`'s `CodeSource`:

```
aClass.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath()
```

When the classes were in a JAR file, this would return the location of the containing JAR file. On my Windows development machine (using Oracle JDK 8), when the classes are in `WEB-INF/classes`, this returns the path to the `WEB-INF/classes` directory within the exploded WAR structure.

However, on our production servers (RHEL 7/CentOS 7, Tomcat 7.0.76, Open JDK 8), in the latter case it returns the full path to the `.class` file itself. I.e., it seems there is a separate `ProtectionDomain` per class file being loaded.

I'm trying to understand what drives creation of different `ProtectionDomain`s in this case. I haven't been able to identify what's different between my Windows development environment and the RHEL production environment. Anybody have any insight?